# JFreeChart axis label in Hours

Tags: java, jfreechart, axis-labels

I have data e.g. (1,3600), (2,4400), ... (33,15000)
Where in (1,3000) 
-> 1 is a number
-> 3600 is seconds

If put in chart, the axis would show the "second" as number.
I have set a code to show axis label in 1 hour interval.

```
// Create an NumberAxis
NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
xAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(3600));

// Assign it to the chart
xyPlot.setDomainAxis(xAxis);
```

So now the axis labels are: 0 ... 3600 ... 7200 ... 10.800 ...

How to make the axis labels show in hours? (0 ... 1 ... 2 ... 3 ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to scale your data by 1000 to represent milliseconds from the [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). Then you can use a `SimpleDateFormat` with a suitable `TimeZone` to get the desired effect.

```
DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Hour");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("H");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
axis.setDateFormatOverride(format);
```

[image]

> The hours are limited to between 0 and 23, any idea how to overcome this?

You can experiment with other formats, e.g. "D:H". Alternatively, scale by 1/3600 to represent hours and use a `NumberAxis` with integer tick units.

```
NumberAxis axis = new NumberAxis();
axis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
```

[image]

Comment: one question, the hours is only limited between 0-23, any idea to overcome this?

Comment: I've elaborated above.